# Laravel 8 Carbon MM/DD/YYYY to Age compared inside join condition

Tags: laravel, join, php-carbon

Table: Search Preferences
Column: search_min_age (two digit number)

Table: Users
Column: birthdate (mm/dd/yyyy)

Both of these are joined together, but here is my error.

> Could not parse 'users.birthdate': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (users.birthdate) at position 0 (u): The timezone could not be found in the database

Here is snippet from my code:

```
    $users = DB::table('users')
                  ->join('search_preferences', function($q) {
                      $q->on('search_preferences.search_type', '=', 'users.account_type')
                          ->on('search_preferences.search_identity', '=', 'users.account_identity')
                          ->on('search_preferences.search_gender', '=', 'users.gender')
                          ->on('search_preferences.search_tribe', '=', 'users.tribe')
                          ->on('search_preferences.search_position', '=', 'users.position')
                          ->on('search_preferences.search_min_age', '<=', Carbon::parse('users.birthdate')->age)
                          ->on('search_preferences.search_max_age', '>=', Carbon::parse('users.birthdate')->age);
                  })
                ->where('users.verified_id', '=', 'yes')
                ->where('search_preferences.user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id)
                ->orderBy('users.id', 'ASC')
                ->select('users.*')
                ->paginate(9);
```

Comment: Can you share full code? Carbon::parse('users.birthdate') means you are trying to parse STRING inside Carbon::parse

Comment: @gguney yes i added the code, thanks for taking a look

Comment: @gguney hey could you take a 2nd look